# Create a stored procedure with parametes that Returns a value

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that returns the ID of a user when the user firstname is entered correctly. Based on the returned ID I would like my IF condiction to return a unqiue number to tell me if user exists in database. I hope that makes sense. Thanks.

```
ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID  
    @UserID int  
AS 

DECLARE @FirstName varchar(50)

set nocount on

SELECT f_Name
FROM tb_User 
WHERE tb_User.f_Name = @FirstName;  

BEGIN
    IF @UserID is not null 
    RETURN 222
    ELSE
    RETURN 333;
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
```

Comment: And what seems to be the problem with your code?

Comment: If a user id is entered that doesn't exist in the DB, it still retuns 222 for good instead of 333. I have wrestled with it for a long time.

Comment: Why do you query @FirstName when it is never set to a value?

Comment: @Shan I think that the OP interchanged the parameter with the return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are checking if the firstname exists in the table, and if it does, return the id for that firstname.. if it does not exist, then you want the procedure to return a code that tells you that the ID is missing

In that case, you want `@FirstName` coming in as a parameter and the @UserId variable gets selected from a matching row in the database

```
ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID  
    @FirstName varchar(50)
AS 

    set nocount on

    DECLARE @UserId INT

    SELECT @UserID = UserId
    FROM tb_User 
    WHERE tb_User.f_Name = @FirstName


    IF @UserID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @UserId = -999
    END

    SELECT @UserId

GO
```

It may be a better idea to check for matches involving both first and last name. Also, what do you do if the name exists multiple times? Use `SET ROWCOUNT 1` to take care of this

```
ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID  
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50)
AS 

    set nocount on

    DECLARE @UserId INT

    SET ROWCOUNT 1

    SELECT @UserID = UserId
    FROM tb_User 
    WHERE tb_User.f_Name = @FirstName
    AND tb_User.l_Name = @LastName

    SET ROWCOUNT 0

    IF @UserID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @UserId = -999
    END

    SELECT @UserId

GO
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfect!!! Also, thank you for both examples, I intend to pass a username and password in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit out parameter

```
create procedure GetUserExists
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @Ret bit out
as
if exists(select *
          from tb_User
          where tb_User.FirstName = @FirstName)
    set @Ret = 1                        
else
    set @Ret = 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the SQL query optimizer is smart enough to scan for only 1 row in the exists () query above. I wonder if the execution plan would differ with a top 1?

Comment: It is smart enough. The query plan is the same with top 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this select query may work:

> SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS   (   SELECT
>   TOP 1 1 
>       FROM tb_User    WHERE tb_User.f_Name = @FirstName   )   THEN
>   1 ELSE 0 END

It will return a 1 if the user exists, 0 otherwise. It should perform more optimally because the use of top 1 (i.e. no need to scan for the existence of more than 1 row).